# How to generate odata v4 c# proxy client for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, odata, visual-studio-2017

Where can i get odata v4 c# proxy generator for Visual Studio 2017? 
The existing one is for 2015 only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VS 2017 is now supported in "[OData Connected Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=laylaliu.ODataConnectedService)" extension. install it and add your reference from:

```
Service Refernces --> Add Connected Service --> OData Connected Service
```

Comment: It is NOT supported! At least not in VS2017 community.

Comment: Note you have to download the "Odata Connected Service" first and restart VS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the download button on [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator) page. You have run the installer and then it works fine with VS2017.

The extension will **not** show up in the `Tools --> Extensions` window, but it will add the *'OData client'* as an option in *'add new item'*.

*Tested this with Visual Studio 2017 enterprise V15.1*

---

**Edit:** Apparently VS2017 is supported again since version `7.4.2 beta`, thanks [@linac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643089/linac).

Comment: @Horosho Hopefully they add official support so you can manage this in Visual Studio. For now this is the best we can do.

Comment: This does not work, if VS2015 and VS2017 installed side by side. This only affects VS2015

Comment: @scher I'm sorry it doesn't work for you. Can't you select the target VS instance in the installer?

Comment: @GWigWam: No, as it just supports VS2015 this version of visual studio is direktly targeted and works fine there. But no option to select VS2017.

Comment: As of now, the OData v4 Client Code Generator does support VS2017 again (7.4.2 beta)

Comment: @linac interesting, but is there any reason to use it? Since the 'OData Connected Service' exists?

Comment: @GWigWam When I tested 'OData Connected Service' earlier today, it did not support the current OData version (7.4.x) because `EdmxReader.Parse()` had to be replaced with `CsdlReader.Parse()`. Other than that one line, in my case the output was the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the solution in VS 2015, update the OData Service Reference from there, then close and reopen in VS 2017.

Clumsy workaround, however it does work in the absence of MS adding the feature back in.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea here would be to create a class library in Visual studio 2015 with the odata code generator. This class library should be responsible for dealing with all the odata client related operations. Next you can simply add this library to your visual studio 2017 solution and add reference to this library in our main project. That is how I got rid of this problem when I encountered it.

Comment: Also hopefully the extension will be available soon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is interested for a version which is running in Visual Studio 2019, s. following post:

[Installing OData v4 Client Code Generator in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003404/installing-odata-v4-client-code-generator-in-visual-studio-2019/58427714#58427714)