# Installing OData v4 Client Code Generator in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I made a OData service and I want to make a client program to call this service. I want to use OData v4 Client Code Generator, but I cannot install it in Visual Studio 2019 and I can only install it in vs2017.

How can I install it in vs2019?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, OData v4 Client Code Generator is not available for VS 2019 in VS Marketplace. However, you can try the following:

**Method 1:**  Exporting your VS 2017 extension to VS 2019, using extension manager extension.

How to: [Using Extension Manager 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/use-your-favorite-extensions-with-visual-studio-2019/)

**Method 2:** You can build the VSIX extension targeting VS 2019.

How to: [Updates to .vsixmanifest](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/)

Project Source: https://github.com/OData/odata.net

Comment: For Method 1 : I cannot install Extension Manager 2017 and it gives me an error in error log

Comment: @Mostafa There are separate versions of Extension Manager for 2017 and 2019. Both are in the marketplace.

Comment: @Mostafa I have re-built the VSIX for VS 2019 by following Method 2.
I have uploaded the vsix here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6a246c8c7c891577e58cd3a273dcda7020190507101609/32f8c2

Comment: Thank you my friend. I installed OData v4 Client Code Generator in vs2019 with this package that you sent. There is another problem. In vs2017 After installing OData v4 Client Code Generator we could add OData Client to the project but in vs2019 I cannot see any OData Client to add.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rahul's download link is expired (and according to the comment of Mostafa, it was missing a feature), I reupload a working version of the extension for Visual Studio 2019:

https://gofile.io/?c=kXvXoR

Some notes about upgrading the vsix file:

1) If you unzip the file, edit the contents (actually even without editing anything), rezip it and finally rename it vsix, it does NOT work. You have to edit the file contents of vsix directly with a program like 7zip.

2) To edit the file contents, I used the following link:
https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1485

I copy the content changes here again:

**extension.vsixmanifest**

```
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[14.0, 17.0)" />
  </Installation>
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,17.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
  </Prerequisites>
```

**manifest.json**

"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor": "[15.0,17.0)"
}

**catalog.json**

```
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor": "[15.0,17.0)"
    },
```

3) After creating the proxy/client, you will notice that the Reference file does not compile because there are some API changes in "Microsoft.OData.Edm": 
- **EdmxReader** has been renamed to **CsdlReader** 
- For **Date** type just remove **.Library** from namespace prefixes. (rename all occurences)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Instead of using OData Client Code Generator in VS2019, I'm using OData Connected Service.

To use this tool to connect to your OData service, you have to follow the next steps:

1. Right Click on the project's name
2. Select "Add" option
3. Click on "Connected Service"
4. On the new window select "OData Connected Service"
5. Write the Service name and place the address of the service (be sure that the service is up and running)
6. Click on finish button and you're done

You may find more information here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/code-generation-tool

Another tool that could be useful is:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unchase.unchaseodataconnectedservice

Comment: May I know why did you downvote this answer? 
What happened when you tried to follow those steps?

Comment: This should me marked as correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment luizs81, maybe @Mostafa votes this one as the right answer.